# Detect ui language in htc sense on android

Tags: android, locale, htcsense

I want to give the users of my app content in the same language as their ui interface. So if someone who has HTC Sense has their ui interface in Norwegian, they should get Norwegian content. However, while HTC Sense has Norwegian UI android does not include the norwegian locale, so the android sdk seems to not use the values-no/strings.xml file. How can I fix this? Basically I want the app to use the resources associated with the ui language of the phone.

Comment: As far as I know HTC sense is not opened even tho it should be.

Comment: I am interested in this also.  My Norwegian users are not seeing my values-no/strings.xml translation.  Will Google ever fix this?

Comment: I guess it will be 'values-nb/strings.xml' instead of 'values-no/strings.xml' ........

Answer (score 0):

I over heard something lately, but this is vague and I don't know if you can at all use for your situation.

I heard that whenever you do some change in the Settings a Broadcast is issued, probably you can subscribe to that and get notified when the locale changed.

Comment: thanks, but no i don't think this will help - people already have their ui set for norwegian, so there is no change in settings...